# Heat map from multiple files with cat, awk or sed (bash)

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I'm dealing with multiple files and I want to plot a heat map `every ::121::600 using 3:25:43` from those files.
Is there a way to combine all files on the fly to get a heat map with commands like:

```
set dgrid3d
splot '< cat data1.csv data2.csv data3.csv data4.csv' every ::121::600 using 3:25:43 w pm3d
```

I tried this but It seems that only the data from data1.csv shows up in the plot. Am I doing something wrong with `'` or `,` ? Is `awk`, or `sed` an option?

i know the option `set table` but I would prefer a clean bash command option to directly make this on the fly.

Is there a good resource to look up all the unix commands with some gnuplot demos?

Thanks so far for the response:
so the `'`are for the plot command: e.g. `plot 'data1.csv' using 1:2 w l` would print row 1 against row 2 from the data1 file with lines. that's why I used to `'`in the command. I found this [Site](http://folk.uio.no/hpl/scripting/doc/gnuplot/Kawano/datafile3-e.html) where hey explain some bash commands for gunplot but I still haven't found what I'm looking for

Thank you for the great respones and help regarding my problem:
This worked:

```
plot '< for i in data1.csv data2.csv data3.csv data4.csv; do cat "$i"; echo; done'  every ::121::600 using 3:25:43 w pm3d
```

Worth mentioning that I  do had to ad the `"`around the `$i`just as vagoberto proposed

and this worked the same way:

```
plot '< awk "FNR==1{print \"\"}1" data1.csv data2.csv data3.csv data4.csv' every ::121::600 using 3:25:43 w pm3d
```

both  worked on my Mac OSX Terminal environment, and on Wind 7 with gnuWin32 Package installed.

Comment: I don't know about gnuplot, but your description gives the impression that you might want [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution). The syntax is `<(cat data*.csv)`. Depending on whether `splot` requires seeking within the input file, this may give you an error, because process substitution basically returns a character device. In Zsh there's an alternative syntax `=(cat data*.csv)` that gives you a seekable file.

Comment: Thanks so far. Is this the correct syntax: `'=(cat data1.csv data2.csv data3.csv data4.csv' every ::121::600 using 3:25:43 w pm3d` I tried it but I get the error that data1 etc. could not be found

Comment: I don't know why you use single quotes around =(). If you use single quotes, then you are no longer using shell features, since you are passing the token literally. Again, I don't know about gnuplot, I'm just speaking from my experience with most *nix command line utilities. Also, as I said, =() only works in zsh.

Comment: @4ae1e1 the shell commands are quoted within gnuplot, e.g. `plot '<(cat data*.csv)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `every ::121::600` command is telling gnuplot to take the data from lines 121 to 600 (counting from 0) on **every block**, and not on every files. You need to pre-process the data to create blocks (put a single line between each data).

Consider the following two data files:

```
#data1.dat          #data2.dat 
1 2                 1.5 2.5           # line 0
3 4                 3.5 4.5           # line 1
5 6                 5.5 6.5           # line 2
```

and try to plot with `every ::2::2` (i.e. plot only line 2).

The following instruction creates a single block, so gnuplot will plot only the point `(5,6)`:

```
cat data1.dat data2.dat
1 2
3 4
5 6
1.5 2.5
3.5 4.5
5.5 6.5
```

The following instruction will create a block for each datafile, so that gnuplot will plot the points `(5,6)` and `(5.5,6.5)`:

```
for i in data*.dat; do cat $i; echo; done
1 2
3 4
5 6

1.5 2.5
3.5 4.5
5.5 6.5
```

You will get a similar result by using `awk 'FNR==1{print ""}1' data*.dat`.

In summary, the following should work:

```
plot '< for i in data*.dat; do cat $i; echo; done' every ::2::2 using 1:2

# or
plot '< awk "FNR==1{print \"\"}1" data*.dat' every ::2::2 using 1:2
```

Comment: thanks a lot (again) for your help, so first I need to cat all the files together into a file, form blocks and then i can spot them? thank you for your help so far

Comment: is there a possibility that the cat command in gunplay on Mac OS X doesn't work?

Comment: When trying the `plot 'for i in data*.dat; do cat $i; echo; done' every ::3::3 using 1:2` i get an expecting {do-clause} error :-( I'm trying it tomorrow again in a windows system . thanks again for the help,

Comment: @PeterS Sorry for the late replay. You can create a new file containing the blocks of data and then plot this file as usual (although it is not necessary since you can pre-process the data as I mentioned in my answer).  I do not use mac OS X nor windows, so I cannot answer if cat should work or not. For the last question, I think you miss the `<` character, and you probably need to quote the `$i` variable (`plot '< for i in data*.dat; do cat "$i"; echo; done' ...`).